# Which one would be better in terms of performance, log4j OR slf4j?

Tags: java, logging, log4j, slf4j

I want to implement loggers in my application. There are two types of loggers JAVA supports.

1. `log4j`
2. `slf4j`

`slf4j` requires less configuration then `log4j` and both supports append functionality. Still I don't understand which one would be better in terms of **performance**?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: The issue is not the *performance*.

Comment: Which one should I prefer?

Comment: Well ... I prefer to use SLF4J in client code and log4j as the underlying logging framework. See more in [SLF4J user manual](http://www.slf4j.org/manual.html).

Comment: You are comparing apples and oranges. LOG4J is a logging implementation, SLF4J is an abstraction layer for logging implementations. A more meaningful question would be about the difference in performance between LOG4J and Logback (or LOG4J2).